# Why does Mesh Deform modifier stop animating after a number of frames?

Tags: animation, mesh, modifiers, armature

Im animating a jump cycle on a character and in order to circumvent cloth physics on a high poly mesh (for things like hair), im using cloth physics on a low poly mesh and then using a Mesh Deform modifier to bind that to the parts I want to obey physics. It works beautifully but only up to about 200 frames, after those frames, those low poly meshes with the cloth physics stop following the armature, they stop wherever they are in the world space and then because they are bound to the mesh create these stretched out meshes as the character moves.

They are properly parented to the armature, bound to the mesh, and it works fine up until those frames. Is this a hardware limitation on my end, or is there some setting I can change?

Comment: I expect the clothe cache end frame needs to be increased.

Comment: wow, beautiful, such a simple resolve to the huge problem I was having, Thanks again!

Answer (score -1, accepted):

user sambler answered my question -
"I expect the clothe cache end frame needs to be increased"